# Running a Data Transform in Python/Pandas in Parallel

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing

I have a medium data(90 gig) transform of financial data that I need to preform. The code in single line execution takes about 2 days to run on the csv files containing the pricing data.

The current workflow I am using loads a large 5 minute price data csv into a pandas df, then converts it to 30 min and writes it to another csv. It isn't a massive cpu undertaking and I'm wondering the most simple way that I could spread this process out over my 8 cores(16 threads)?

Comment: If you're running Python 3, then [concurrent.futures' ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) is the canonical way to do multiprocessing.

Comment: If you're running Python 2, take a look at [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org).  It can run on all the cores of one machine or on a cluster of machines, including Amazon EC2. Spark also supports parallel execution of Java and Scala.  I have some introductory notes on Spark on my blog [here](http://blog.sunshineonacloudy.net/2015/06/introduction-to-apache-spark_64.html).